# Ipywidgets not showing in Voila app deployed with Heroku for some (not all) users

Tags: python, heroku, ipywidgets, voila

I have a pretty basic Heroku app made in Python with Jupyter and Voila. The app consists of a few ipywidgets that need to be filled in order to run a piece of code, which then goes to show a graph.

The app is working just fine for me, but is not working for a colleague of mine. The app does load for him, but the widgets (circled in red in the picture below) are not showing. He only sees the texts.

Any idea what might cause this? Since the app is working fine for me, I was thinking there isn't something wrong with the app, but maybe it's something on his machine. But it's not working on both his computer and phone though...

EDIT: Solved

Answer (score 1):

Disabling adblocker did the trick!